# jquery toggle is skipping every other item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript and JQuery. Right now, i am trying to make a comment system where you click reply to bring up  containing the form. But for some reason, first comment reply brings up the form but not the next comment. And I can bring up reply  for 3rd comment but not 4th. This goes on and on. Here is the function of php for getting comments.

```
function display_children($parent, $level){
global $db_upload;
global $comments;
if ($adj = $db_upload->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE parent_id = '$parent' AND url_id = '$comments'")){

    if ($adj->num_rows){
    while ($row = $adj->fetch_assoc()){

    echo str_repeat("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|", $level). $row['m_username']. " on ". $row['date'].'<br>';
    echo str_repeat("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|", $level).$row['comment'].'<br>'.'<br>';
?>


<a href="#" class="mix">
<small>reply</small><br><br><br>
</a>
<div class="reply_comment" style="display:none">

<table>
<tr><td>
<textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" id="comment_process" value="save" />
<input type="hidden" id="c" value="<?php echo $cmt; ?>">
</tr></td>
</table>

</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="../secure/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="message.js"></script>   


<?php
    display_children($row['id'], $level+1);
}
}
}
}
```

And here is the jquery that I am using

```
$('.mix').click(function(){
$(this).next('.reply_comment').toggle();
});
```

Comment: What does Chrome inspector say in the Console when you click on the even number "reply" links? Any JS errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console. I am very new to these.

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly including the same JS files over and over:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../secure/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="message.js"></script>
```

You should only need these once (after you include jquery).

You should also action these by "ID" not by class.

So do the following:

```
<?php
function display_children($parent, $level){
  global $db_upload;
  global $comments;

  if ($adj = $db_upload->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE parent_id = '$parent' AND url_id = '$comments'")) {
    if ($adj->num_rows) {
      while ($row = $adj->fetch_assoc()) {

      echo str_repeat("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|", $level). $row['m_username']. " on ". $row['date'].'<br>';
      echo str_repeat("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp|", $level).$row['comment'].'<br>'.'<br>';
?>


  <a href="#" class="mix" data-commentboxid="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
  <small>reply</small><br><br><br>
  </a>
  <div id="post-id-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="reply_comment" style="display:none">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text_for-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="comment_process_for-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="save" />
        <input type="hidden" id="c_for-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $cmt; ?>">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  </div>

  <?php
      display_children($row['id'], $level+1);

      }
    }
  }
}

?>
```

and your JS becomes:

```
$('.mix').click(function(){
    $('#post-id-' + (this).attr('data-commentboxid')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the code but it seems something is still not right. When I included the scripts in the head, whole jquery stops working.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes here:

- You are having multiple items with the same ID in html (you can only have one);
- You have switched the closing row and closing cell tags just before you close the table. This might cause your actual problem;
- You are including the same scripts over and over (these script should probably not be included in this function but somewhere in the head or the foot of your page).

You should validate your html as that is the probable cause of your problem.

Comment: I changed ID into class, I am dumb to switch </td></tr>,  I included script in the head but then jquery does not work as a whole.

Comment: @user3131412 Have you checked the html with an html validator? Also, do you have an example online? Either way you should post your html and not your php as the problem is not related to php.

Comment: I think the problem was caused by too many duplicates of scrips and php includes. Since I got it to work on a fresh page, I am going to add things as I go by. Thank you for the reponse.